# Android Change picture every 10 seconds

Tags: android, image

Im trying to write a very basic android app that displays around 5 pictures one after each other on the screen. I want it to display a different picture after about 10 seconds. Can anyone advise me on how I would go around this. Below i have outlined what i would be looking for.

Picture 1
Picture 2
Picture 3
Picture 4
Picture 5

display full screen Picture 1
wait 10 seconds
Remove Picture 1 and Display Picture 2
Wait 10 seconds
Remove Picture 2 and Display Picture 3
Wait 10 seconds
Remove Picture 3 and Display Picture 4
Wait 10 seconds
Remove Picture 4 and Display Picture 5
Wait 10 seconds

Start again

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Have you considered using [Frame Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame)?

You can specify an xml in your anim folder that contains a frame-by-frame animation, specifing each image duration, and other settings, check it out

**UPDATE**

You can also build a frame animation programmatically of course:

```
    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image2), 500);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image3), 300);
    animation.setOneShot(false);

    ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

    // start the animation!
    animation.start()
```

Comment: thanks, that worked really well, im an android novice and im programming something for a tablet using 3.1 when i run the app on my virtual android device it brings up a much smaller screen in like portrait is there anyway to fix this and is there any easy way to make an image view fill the screen? Thankyou so much

Comment: try putting this on the ImageView xml properties: android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent". And then set also the android:scaleType property with the value you need. Look at this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html

Comment: can we do this for wallpaper service ?

Answer (score 8):

create blink.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/Picture_1" android:duration="10000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/Picture_2" android:duration="10000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/Picture_3" android:duration="10000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/Picture_4" android:duration="10000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/Picture_5" android:duration="10000" />
</animation-list>
```

put blink.xml in drawable folder and
in activity Code write this.

```
ImageView mImageView ;
mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView); //this is your imageView
mImageView .setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.blink));
```

then you will get what you want.!

Comment: AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable();
frameAnimation.start();  you should add these lines too, to start animation.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the `CountDownTimer`  : follow these steps :

1) declare an `array` which will contain the identifients of your pictures

2 ) declare the `CountDownTimer` like this :

```
int i=0;
new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    imgView.setImageDrawable(sdk.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(array[i]));
                    i++;
                    if(i== array.length-1) i=0;
                    start();
                }
            }.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a [`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) that executes the change you want (I suppose it will be changing an `ImageView`'s bitmap/drawable), and post them with delay to the main thread loop, using a `Handler` and its [`postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method.

To make it a loop, you could have the runnable post itself.