# Fade In and Out animation in Android

Tags: android, fadein, fadeto

I need to create an `animation` in android,i have one fixed image in the screen, i need to add another `image` over the previous image using fade in and out.

i have searched and i found something like this

[Fade in and out in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796139/fade-in-fade-out-android-animation-in-java)

That is the concept, but can i add different image using this method,i have tried simple animation technique also but that is working in every version.

Could somebody help me @Thanks

Comment: Why not you are viewing the API DEMO section given by Android.. There is alot of animations ..

Comment: Goto sdk->samples->ANDROID_VERSION->ApiDemos  and find a package for animation. If you want to real time check start emulator. you will see the API Demo application, start and check animations

Comment: refer this link http://www.example8.com/category/view/id/15551

Comment: Check Frame Animation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125936/android-change-picture-every-10-seconds

Comment: @lassana i have tried that but its working fine in 4.0 version but not in 2.2,2.3

Comment: @PankajKumar thanks i found it i need to know that without onclick,fadein and out  in certain time interval

Comment: @sunil thanks i need to know that without onclick,fadein and out in certain time interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public class MyAnimationListener implements AnimationListener {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg);
        i.startAnimation(animo);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

In Second Activity:

```
MyAnimationListener mListener = new MyAnimationListener();
        anim.setAnimationListener(mListener);
        i.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: in your first animation put your fixed image and on end of first animation put your second animation with second image and start it.