# Changing the picture of the button continuously for a specific time

Tags: android, button

Is it possible to change the picture of the button with a sequence of images from the drawable continuously for a specific time on the click of the button , I know little about frame animation , is it possible to apply frame animation for changing the pictures of the button  ? If not is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: what u want to do ? changing the button image on a click event or automatically ?

Comment: You want to change the picture randomly from your drawable?

Comment: ya from the drawable on the click of the button

Comment: Please try to explain your Question in a way that we can understand it properly. We are not here provide you the code for your incomplete question that you given

Comment: @Akhilesh i dint ask for the code , i will try to elaborate the question

Comment: Hello. its very easy to do. you only need to change button background on button click. You have implemented button onClickListener and in that you can get view by id that which button is pressed and change its background accordingly. Hope this answer help you.

Comment: Not very clear question, can you elaborate more ?

Comment: I know about setting the background of the button , but is it possible to use frame animation for doing so , since i have to replace the background with more than 1 image for a particular time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please consider frame animation:

```
AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1), 1000);
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image2), 1000);
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image3), 1000);
animation.setOneShot(false);

Button btnAnimation =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtn);
btnAnimation.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);


//In OnCreate or button_click event you can fire animation

animation.start()
```

I stole the answer from the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125936/android-change-picture-every-10-seconds).

If you want to change the background for every click You can call the following :

```
    private int pics[]=  {R.drawable.p1, R.drawable.p2, R.drawable.p3, R.drawable.p4, R.drawable.p5};
private Random rand = new Random();

public int set_rand_pic() {
    int pos = rand.nextInt(pics.length-1);
    mycard.setBackgroundResource(pics[pos]);
    return pos; 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Countdown Timer.

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

//Change the button Bachground here!
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
//set the button background that you want to show on end
     }
  }.start();   

thats all :) enjoy
```